# Showing initial value of input

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field for which i want to show some default or initial value. After that whenever user changes the value it should change but initial value should be what I give. But I am not able to do this. Here is my input

```
<input placeholder={this.props.edit_tag_reducer.time_in}
       id="time_in"
       type="text"
       value={this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.start)}
/>
```

I tried `defaultValue={this.props.edit_tag_reducer.time_in}` also, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the value you're passing in is not null or undefined?

Comment: Which library / template engine / framework are you using? Please tag.

Comment: What does `{this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.start)}` return? Because that should certainly provide a `value` to the element.

Comment: That is providing the correct value. But placeholder is not providing the desired value. {this.props.edit_tag_reducer.time_in} is not undefined also. When I console it, it get's printed

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enclose in quotes:

`value='"' + {this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.start)} + '"'`

This will act as the default (initial) value. (There is no defaultValue property.)

If this doesn't show a value it is because your property isn't correct or it doesn't convert to Hms.

You can just try `value="1:10:35" to test where the issue lies

Given your question is ambiguous, you might be looking to get the placeholder tag working.

Same thing applies. Enclose it in quotes:

`placeholder= '"' + {this.props.edit_tag_reducer.time_in} + '"'`

Comment: there is no problem in value. I have problem in defaulValue.

Comment: The initial value is your default (starting) value.

Comment: See the edited answer if you are trying to make placeholder work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to have both a `placeholder` and a `value` attribute on your input box, because the placeholder is used for when a value is missing initially or missing altogether, but because you're setting it, you're not going to need it I don't think.

Also keep in mind, the value attribute listed here only affects the DOM, it's not actually the value of that input in JS.

And make sure `{this.props...}` actually contains a value you want.

Comment: I want to show a default value. Then if a user wants to change it then he can chenge. In my case it will be changed via {this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.start)}

Comment: Make sure your object is actually returning a value, but if it is, just wrap the entire things in quotes and it should work.